# React-Native Hybrid App: Pop UIViewController that embeds RCTRootView

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, react-native

I'm integrating components in an existing iOS app written in Objective-C/Swift.

As a root view controller of my app, I use an `UINavigationController`.

In one of the multiple view controllers of my app, I have a button that push a View Controller in the Navigation Controller that contains the following code:

```
@objc class ReactNativeViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    let jsCodeLocation = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true")

    let contactsView = RCTRootView(bundleURL: jsCodeLocation, moduleName: "MainComponent", initialProperties: nil, launchOptions: nil)

    self.view.addSubview(contactsView)
    contactsView.frame = self.view.bounds;
  }
}
```

`MainComponent` returns a `Navigator` that manage multiple React-Native components:

```
return (
  <Navigator
    initialRoute={initialRoute}
    renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
      if (route.component) {
        return <route.component navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps} />;
      }
    }}
    navigationBar={
      <Navigator.NavigationBar
        routeMapper={this.NavigationBarRouteMapper}
        style={styles.navBar}
      />
    }
  />
);
```

That workflow works fine. The only thing I need is a way to pop `ReactNativeViewController` from my `UINavigationController` when the button `Back` has been hit on the main React-Native component.

I tried the following but with no luck:

- Create a Native Module with a single method `popLastViewController` that pop the displayed UIViewController that is displayed from the UINavigationController:

  ```
  @implementation RNNavigationControllerBridge

  RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

  RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(popLastViewController) {
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];

    [navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
  }

  @end
  ```
- Call the above method when back button has been hit:

  ```
  onPress={() => {
    if (index === 0) {
      NativeViewsManager.popLastViewController();
    } else {
      navigator.pop();
    }
  }}
  ```

But that doesn't work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi, your setting here the root view as same in the appdelegate or another root?

Comment: The one from the appdelegate

Comment: I want to know what is the difference between setting the root view in app delegate and in this view controller? How will it be useful if we set the root view in view controller? 
Plz, help me on this...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem solved!

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(popLastViewController) {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];

    [navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  });
}
```

Comment: please add answer for swift